# focus on opened application window cmd nircmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am trying to open 2 files using a batch file.

created a loop to paste( alternately )something in that file.

i.e

1) Paste some thing in file 1.

2) Paste some thing in file 2.

3) Paste something in file 1.

4) Paste something in file 2

..and so on

**problem is that how can I focus back on file 1 after I have done writing in file 2 ?**

Note: 
I am using nircmd.exe utility.

Code sample in my batch file:

**

```
START file1.txt
START file2.txt
FOR LOOP STARTS (
nircmd.exe win focus stitle "file1.txt"  ---> not working, is there something I  am missing?
nircmd.exe sedkeypress h e l l o
nircmd.exe win focus stitle "file2.txt"  ---> not working, something missing ?
nircmd.exe sedkeypress b y e
)
```

**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't get `nircmd` to work either, maybe it's not a reliable utility, or is now broken on Windows 8.1 (my Windows ver). I'd recommend [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for stuff like this; it's quite powerful.

Comment: I'd use [WshShell.AppActivate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with a [batch + JScript hybrid](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433).  You can coerce [PowerShell to use it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730976.aspx) if you prefer, although invoking PowerShell is slower than cscript.  If you insist on using `nircmd.exe`, could you use `tasklist /v | find "file1.txt"` to get the PID and focus by PID instead?

Comment: _Paste some thing in file_: paste where? Ahead of actual content? Behind it? Somewhere else? With / without some text separator (a space, tab, `CrLf`)?

Comment: @josefz paste ahead, in the file. But the real problem is about Focus on the file.

Comment: @rojo will try to use this way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For NirCMD I found that `nircmd win activate stitle "App Name"` on Win10 was the ticket over `focus` and `settopmost`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem in *getting* focus on a window, but in *keeping it on* as in Windows focus could become changed by any of (much) (unforeseen) (asynchronous) events...

Next approach could help to write a text ahead of a `.txt` file content:

```
echo(h e l l o>"%temp%\temp.xxx"
:: echo( w o r l d>>"%temp%\temp.xxx"
copy nul + "%temp%\temp.xxx" + "file1.txt" "file1.txt"
erase /Q /F "%temp%\temp.xxx"
```

The `.xxx` file extension could be replaced by any possibly unused extension, for instance `.xyz`